# VS Code: how to add all default snippet of HTML files into react js files?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I have learnt html, js and css. Now I want to learn React.
Now I am very used to use snippets of HTML files such as `div.className` and by pressing enter it gives me `<div class="className"></div>`.
When using React the HTML part is in return in a js file.
How can I add all default snippet in VS Code of HTML files into react js files?

Comment: You probably will have to move from the "JS context" to the "XML context" first - `div.className` is totally valid javascript and should not be expanded to anything. Try typing `<>div.className` or something like that

Comment: @mistertl: Hope my answer has helped you. If it has would like you to Accept and vote for my answer... This will help other developers as well... Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have `Emmet` extension Installed in `VSCode`.

Then you need to add this line of Code in your `settings.json` of VSCode Settings and you will have all the `emmet` formatting for JSX.

```
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
```

And also if not already set, you will need these two settings as well.

```
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

And `Emmet` will start to format your JSX just like it does in normal HTML

Answer (score 4):

**If you can`t find Emmet plugin**

According to [official page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) no need to add extension. checked on version 1.51

> Support for Emmet snippets and expansion is built right into Visual Studio Code, no extension required. Emmet 2.0 has support for the majority of the Emmet Actions including expanding Emmet abbreviations and snippets.

Just press **cmd+P** (macOS) or **ctrl+P** (others)
and type **settings.json**, open this file and as mentioned **@Imran Rafiq Rather** add this line `"emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "javascriptreact" },`

And that's it!

Answer (score 2):

first install **emmet** extension in **vscode**
second got to preferences/setting.json
ans put this

```
 "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
      },
```

it will work

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2022, here is what I do.

1. Go to Settings
2. Click Extensions
3. Click Emmet
4. In Include Languages section, Add Item with `Item` = "javascript" and `Value` = "javascriptreact"
5. Click OK

[image: image reference]