# Reactjs JSX autocompleting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am using reactjs with VSCode. Anytime am writing JSX with classname or an id i have to do it manually. Anyone who knows how to achieve autocompleting for elements with classname or id. For example in normal html while using vs code it is possible to write `div#myclassname` or `div.myidname` and VSCode editor gives you suggestion to autocomplete. Thanks in advance.

Comment: vscode does it automatically. Try to upgrade or reinstalling vscode

Comment: I have answered it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65531028/vs-code-how-to-add-all-default-snippet-of-html-files-into-react-js-files/65531120#65531120

Hope this helps dear Sam :)

Comment: @Sam welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install the ES7 React/Redux/Graphql/React Native snippets extension.